# How can I push elements out of a forEach() context?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, iteration

This is my first post ever :)

So what I am trying to do is loop through keys of an object with a forEach() loop and for each element, push specific values into an array. Then after the loop, resolve the array containing all pushed values.

As I understand, it's hard to get out values of the forEach() context. Is there a way to do something like that ?

Here's a code exemple of what I'm trying to do:

```
    some function returning a promise
    ... 
    ...

    let promisesArray = [];

    //Loop on each object from data and do whatever
    ObjectJSON.array.forEach((object) => {
      if (object.key === "foo") {
        functionBar()
          .then((response) => {
            promisesArray.push(
              `Object: ${object.key}  |  ${object.someOtherKey}`
            );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      }
    });

    resolve(promisesArray);

  }); //end of promise's return
```

Right now, it returns an empty array.

The expected result should be something like this instead:

```
[
  'Object: key1  |  someOtherKey1',
  'Object: key2  |  someOtherKey2',
  'Object: key3  |  someOtherKey3',
  ...
]
```

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: pls provide reproducible example

Comment: This reeks of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). And no, [you cannot use `forEach` for an asynchronous loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572).

Comment: I would strongly suggest you read through the [`javascript.info/async`](https://javascript.info/async) chapter. It will walk you through the core principles of working with asynchronous operations in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on your first post ever!

It's a super classic question though, how to use an asynchronous function in a loop. With `.forEach` you can't, but you can using `await` in a `for` loop :

```
let promisesArray = [];

for (let object of ObjectJSON.array) {
  if (object.key !== "foo") continue;

  const response = await functionBar();

  promisesArray.push(
    `Object: ${object.key}  |  ${object.someOtherKey}`
  );
}

resolve(promisesArray);
```

Using `await` will probably require your function to be marked as `async` (`async function doSomething() { ...` )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
By using "await", can I handle errors like using a .then().catch() promise ?

Comment: Yes, you encapsulate the `await` in a `try{ }catch` block. I have updated my answer. Also, if it solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted!

Comment: Alrighty then ! Thanks a lot !